# How to start intent activity when context menu clicked?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contextmenu

I already had success on create the floating context menu when I long click one item on list view. However, when I click the menu on context menu there is nothing happening. I want to make it to start a new activity. Is there something wrong?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_view);

    dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);

    dataSource.open();

    values = dataSource.getAllMahasiswa();

    ArrayAdapter<Mahasiswa> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Mahasiswa>
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);



}
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        menu.add(0, 1000, 0, "Edit");  
        menu.add(0, 1001, 0, "Hapus"); 

} 

public boolean onContextMenuItemSelected(MenuItem item){
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case 1000:             
           Intent i = new Intent(ActivityView.this, Tes.class);

           startActivity(i);
       break; 
       case 1001:
          //not yet
       break;
       }
       return super.onContextItemSelected(item);           

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.pick_camera:

            break;
        }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

with

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {

         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_options, menu);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
```

create image_options.xml in menu folder of resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/pick_camera"
        android:title="Use Camera">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: thx for reply. i have tried it but even got confused @_@. sory im to noob :(
so on my case. the floating context menu is already appear. first menu is "Edit" and second "Hapus". but when i click that "Edit" the activity doesnt start. so i tried for a toast msg. and even the toast didnt work too. so maybe there is wrong on my context menu? :( please look at my list too on top. thx :)

Comment: I checked this, everything is fine.Try to change android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1  to your layout to make your listview and also change the adapter then try.